# pointer minus pointer in array and variable

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, subtraction

Can anyone help me with this.
I thought pointer is a object that hold address of a variable. So when i minus a pointer to a pointer. it get this result.

```
int a = 2;
int b = 7;
int* c = &a;
int* d = &b;
int e = c - d; // = 3


int array[] = { 1, 2, 6, 4, 7, 8, 5, 3 };
int* f = &array[0];
int* g = &array[8];
int h = g - f; // = 8
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. You've made an observation, but you have not asked a question. What surprises you about the result? What did you expect and how is that different from what you observed?

Comment: Note that `int e = c - d;` is not allowed. You may only subtract pointers that point to elements from the same array.

Comment: i want to know how that happended. @FrançoisAndrieux i ran and it worked.

Comment: It is Undefined Behavior. That means the compiler is not required to produce an error, and anything can happen. When I try it, I get `e == -1;`. Any result is possible, including a crash or no result at all. For `h` the result is always 8 because that is the result of subtracting the elements' index in `array`.

Comment: Note that it is a gray area whether `&array[8]` is allowed or not, because the last element is `array[7]` but you can get a pointer to one-past-the-end, as long as it is not evaluated.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux a one-past-the-end pointer can be *evaluated* (such as when used in pointer arithmetic), it just can’t be *dereferenced*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, a pointer holds address of an object in the memory. In C and C++ we can do pointer arithmetic which lets us subtract pointers from each other and more. Substracting pointers gives us the distance between the two addresses in the memory. The unit of the distance is determined by the pointer type. Meaning that subtracting two `int*`s will give you how many `int`s are your addresses apart. In your case variable `e` will be the distance between where `a` is stored in memory and where `b` is stored in the memory. Running your code I got `e=1`. Which I expect because `a` and `b` are defined right after each other so its expected that they will occupy two adjacent spaces on the stack but I guess its something that the compiler decides.
for arrays On the other hand, by definition all the elements are stored one after the other therefore the distance between the first and eighth element of any array is always `8`. Also take a look at the code below:

```c
int a = 2;
int b = 7;
int* c = &a;
int* d = &b;
int e = d - c; // e=1
//the unit of measurement for pointer subtraction is the type of the pointer
//therefore although first byte of b is stored 4 bytes (sizeof(int)) after the
//first byte of a, we get '1' as the distance. but we cast the pointer to another type
//say char, we get distance based on that type
int f= (char*)d-(char*)c;//f=4 or e*4 since sizeof(int)=4*sizeof(char) (on this particular environment)
```

Comment: The question is tagged C++, and `d - c` is Undefined Behavior in that language. Maybe it is allowed in C, I'm not sure. There is no correct, incorrect or expected result.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux — it’s not allowed I C, either.

Comment: There is nothing in C or C++ that requires `a` and `b` to be adjacent to each other, nor to be allocated in the order of their declaration. This answer describes common behavior, but it is not something you can count in. With another compiler I used to use, the difference would have been `-1`.

Answer (score 2):

In your first example, subtracting independent pointers makes no sense. Considering your example :

```cpp
int a = 2;
int b = 7;
int* c = &a;
int* d = &b;
int e = c - d; // Nonsense
```

If what you're trying to do is the operation "2 - 7" using pointers, then you first have to dereference your pointers (evaluate the value held by the variable pointed by your pointer) :

```cpp
int e = (*c) - (*d);
```